# ScrollView Still comes Behind out of it's Area

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

This Is My Xml.
.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xxx.xxx.MyActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewFromDateToDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtFromDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/timesheet_icon"
            android:editable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:hint="@string/txtFromDate"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:onClick="selectDate"
            android:textSize="@dimen/generalTextSize" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/lblFromTo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="@dimen/generalTextSize" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtToDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/timesheet_icon"
            android:editable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:hint="@string/txtToDate"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:onClick="selectDate"
            android:textSize="@dimen/generalTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/green_button_department"
            android:text="@string/btnShowData"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/upperSeparator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewFromDateToDate"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewTimeOffDetailsHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/upperSeparator"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:text="@string/txtHeaderTimeOff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/generalTextSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="@string/txtHeaderDate"
            android:textSize="@dimen/generalTextSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/txtHeaderHours"
            android:textSize="@dimen/generalTextSize" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txtHeaderAction"
            android:textSize="@dimen/generalTextSize" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/lowerSeparator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/viewTimeOffDetailsHeader"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollDiv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lowerSeparator" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewTimeOffDetailsArea"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewTimeOffDetailsFooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/green_button_department"
            android:text="@string/btnSubmitTimeOff"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want my LinerLayout `scrollDiv` to Be in Between of `lowerSeparator` and `viewTimeOffDetailsFooter`  But the problem is ScrolView is still displaying it's Elements After `viewTimeOffDetailsFooter` Starts. 
.
Here is an output. 
[Of XML Layout](http://s284.photobucket.com/user/firoz_shaikh/media/stack_zpsudl3gitu.jpg.html)

Here you can see the Buttons of `scrollDiv` Still Displays after `viewTimeOffDetailsFooter` Buttons. I know that i should not put whole File But i am not getting proper solution that's why. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to place it above the viewTimeOffDetailsFooter, by adding below attribute to your scrollDiv

```
    android:layout_above="@+id/viewTimeOffDetailsFooter"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `viewTimeOffDetailsFooter` doesn't have any positional link with `scrollDiv`, so add to it new rule `android:layout_below="@id/scrollDiv"`. It can work only without `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` rule - need to try.